# How can I test which node comes first?

Tags: javascript, dom, nodes

I have two given nodes that are stored inside variables. Is there a simple, low resource usage, solution to find which node comes first in the document? Both nodes should be siblings but may be many nodes apart.

Comment: Is this related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208624/check-if-element-is-before-or-after-another-element-in-jquery . I would use the second answer

Comment: @JosephYoung I'm looking for a pure JavaScript solution because I'm planning to use this in relation to an algorithm that moves nodes around and I'm worried that JQuery might break the algorithm. I will read some of the answers though :) Thank you.

Comment: @JosephYoung All the answers for that question appear to contain JQuery.

Comment: If you know for sure that they are siblings, have you looked into using `nextSibling`? Starting with node A, you could write a simple function that uses `nextSibling` and check if it is indeed node B. If you iterate over all siblings and can't find node B, node A is the second.

Comment: @Steve Something I didn't mention (but I will add it right now to the question) is that these nodes are in the same level but may be many nodes between them.

Comment: @ww139 It doesn't matter how many nodes are in between. If they are siblings you just need to iterate over them using `nextSibling` (or `previousSibling` as adeneo suggests below)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try [`compareDocumentPosition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Node/compareDocumentPosition):

```
function theFirst(node1, node2) {
  return node1.compareDocumentPosition(node2)
    & Node.DOCUMENT_POSITION_FOLLOWING ? node1 : node2;
}
```

Note that if the nodes are in different trees, the result may be random (but consistent). You can filter out that case with `& Node.DOCUMENT_POSITION_DISCONNECTED` and return e.g. `undefined`.

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle/code snippet with this code? Thank you for this answer. +1

Comment: I have implemented this code and it appears to be more efficient. I will accept this as best answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work

```
function isAfter(n1, n2) {
    var prev = n1.previousSibling,
        res  = true;

    while (prev) {
        if ( prev === n2 ) {
            prev = res = false;
        } else {
            prev = prev.previousSibling;
        }
    }
    return !!res;
}
```

Just iterate upwards using `previousSibling` (or downwards using `nextSibling`) from the first node, and compare against the second node to see if comes after (or before) the first one.
When there's no more siblings, `previousSibling returns`null` and the loop ends.

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/zo199n2f/1/)

Comment: I have implemented this code and it works. However, I now see the other answer and it may be more efficient because it doesn't involve an algorithm. +1 :)