# Given arbitrary markup, which element appears first and which is second

Tags: jquery, dom

As the title says, given a DOM of unknown or arbitrary structure, and two known elements in that DOM, how can I use jQuery to determine which one occurs first and which one occurs second?

This question is similar to [Check if element is before or after another element in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208624/check-if-element-is-before-or-after-another-element-in-jquery) but is different in that that question is only asking for order among siblings. This question is asking in the context of a generally unknown DOM structure. The two elements could be siblings, ancestor/descendant, great-uncle, second-cousins-twice-removed, or anywhere else in the DOM.

**EDIT** Order is determined by which appears first in the markup.

Comment: Define occurs first and occurs second? First in a tree? First defined?  Etc.

Comment: I dont see the ambiguity in this question and I'm not sure I see the difference in your cases, but I believe I have clarified my question for you. Ordering would be first in the markup, which would seem to me to be the same as first defined.

Comment: Also, what code have you written to test what you're after?

Comment: Honestly, I'm having trouble coming up with an algorithm that would even work. The problem is beyond my skills, which is why I am asking for support.

Answer (score 1):

I am puzzled why you insist on jquery for such a simple task.

```
(nodeA.compareDocumentPosition(nodeB) & Node.DOCUMENT_POSITION_PRECEDING) != 0
```

[MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/compareDocumentPosition)